# height: 100% on tablet device

Tags: css, height, tablet

I have created a website with two full height divs next to each other and it works fine on my desktop computer (Chrome, Mozilla and IE). However on my tablet (Android) the divs are not full height and only wraps around the text?

Does anyone know why that is?

This fiddle displays the basic layout I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/yt22tcmq/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.parent{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.left{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.right{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

(BTW the fiddle gave a 404 error on my tablet but works on my desktop.)

Comment: I can't test it but have you tried to just add padding: 0; to html and body ?

Comment: Try using 100vh instead of 100% on your .parent class.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud I just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Someone I tried that ealier, but it only adjusts the height to the browser display height so it won't work if the content is longer than the screen height.